# Line integral over closed curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Show that :

$$\int x\cos z dx +y\sin z dy+z dz = 0$$ for all closed curves $\gamma $ that are paralell with the xy plane.

So z= C , how do I show this for all closed curves ? is there some general parametrisation of closed curves ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know the Green's formula?

Comment: yes but only for fields in R^2 we didint do more than that yet.

Comment: That will do because when you set $z=constant$ you are left with a plane which is parallel to the $xy$-plane. This plane is essentialy $R^2$ because its coordinates are of the form $(x,y,constant)$ which you can identify with $(x,y,0)$ or better with just $(x,y)$.

Comment: Thanks i solved it :)

Comment: Great! Glad I could help